# Are there differences in the frequency certain champion/rare affixes occur?

Tags: diablo-iii

Last night I noticed that almost every champion/rare pack I came across had Mortar as one of their prefixes.  I believe, out of the dozen or two I fought, only 3-4 packs did not have Mortar.

It seemed like more than half had Plagued.

Yet only two had illusionist.  Only one had Horde.  Only one had Invulnerable Minions (thank goodness!). Only two had Avenger.

In all the time I've spent playing (I'm up to Act II Inferno), I've only ever seen Missle Dampening once.

I know that some affixes only become available at higher difficulties (e.g. Invulnerable Minions only appears in Hell or Inferno), and some are only possible on rares or champion packs, but not both (e.g. Horde only appears on rares, and Health Link only appears on champion packs).  But setting aside those restrictions, are some affixes "rare" on their own?

Is there any information about the relative frequency with which each affix appears?  Is Missle Dampening really just uber-rare?  Did I just get ridiculously unlucky with the RNG last night with all the Mortar Jailer Plagued X monsters I fought?

Comment: I seem to never see Missile Dampening, but I swear if Arcane Enchanted and/or Desecrator isn't on a champ/rare pack, I'd assume my game was broken.

Comment: I have yet to see a missile dampening monster and I've seen (and killed) a heck lot of uniques/champions.

Comment: I can't confirm this, but it seems like when one affix is on a monster in that area, other monsters in that area have a higher chance of having that same affix.  I only notice this usually when there's an affix on a monster that I absolutely hate (teleporter, waller, etc) so it could be just selective memory working.

Comment: Yeah, Missile Dampening is very rare; I've only seen it 2 or 3 times, ever. By contrast, Arcane Enchanted is all over the place, and Mortar is also very common.

Comment: I'm only on nightmare, and I've seen Missile Dampening twice... maybe I am just unlucky :(

Comment: I've encountered more fire chains/health links than missile dampening. I'd say that dampening is one of the rarer effects.

Comment: now that patch 1.03 is out, I've encountered missile dampening a lot (because they fixed the nether tentacles thing).

Comment: @yx. I had two missile dampening in a single run the day the patch came out, doubling my total encounters with them. But it wasn't mentioned in the patch notes, so I'm sure they didn't actually change anything, and it is merely a "coincidence" ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ben says, there are three types of affixes.  These are broken up as follows:

- Strong CC (limit of one):

  - Knockback
  - Nightmarish
  - Vortex
- Defensive (limit of one):

  - Avenger (Champion pack only)
  - Extra Health
  - Health Link (Champion pack only)
  - Horde (Boss only)
  - Illusionist
  - Missile Dampening (Boss only)
  - Invulnerable Minions (Boss only)
  - Shielding
  - Vampiric
- Aggressive (no limit):

  - Arcane Enchanted
  - Descrator
  - Electrified
  - Fast
  - Fire Chains (Champion pack only)
  - Frozen
  - Jailer
  - Molten
  - Mortar
  - Plagued
  - Reflects Damage
  - Teleporter
  - Waller

So any affixes from the Aggressive category has a much higher chance of being seen, i.e. Mortar and Plagued, while an affix like Missile Dampening will only appear for Boss packs (not Champion packs) and only has a one in seven chance if they have a Defensive ability.  This results in a much lower chance of being seen.

Note that while CC and defensive categories have a limit of one from each of them, that doesn't mean that a group *must* have one of each of them.  I believe they can roll with only one of two, or even neither of the two, i.e. solely aggressive affixes.

Answer (score 0):

There are three categories of affixes:

- defensive
- offensive
- CC

Each champion pack can only have one defensive, one CC and as many offensive as they want. I cannot get my hand on Bashiok's post about this but I remember there were about three defensive affixes, three or four CC and around seven or eight offensive.

So a champion could come in with four offensive affixes or three offensive and one defensive. You get the point.

So if there can only be one defensive and one cc there has to be way more offensive affixes on a mob, which would explain why we see offensive affixes more than other.

Comment: Here, have the source: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/6079707996#1